# i3wm changes to config have no effect

Tags: shortcut-keys, i3-wm, tiling

Editing config file for i3 windows manager located at `'/etc/i3/config'`. I tried changing the font size from 12 to 20 in the default file:

```
font pango:monospace 20
```

Also tried commenting out a few commands like shifting between windows.

I then reboot but i3 functions as it always had even when trying to do the commented out commands.

It seems i3 isn't using the config I'm expecting it to. How can I go about debugging this?

Comment: is there i3 config file in this address ?
~/.i3/config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run this command

```
i3-config-wizard
```

then config file created in location

```
~/.config/i3/config
```

now you can edit it .

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to edit your config again and want to use this from `/etc/i3/config`, you can copy this file to `~/.config/i3/`

Just type in terminal: `cp /etc/i3/config ~/.config/i3/config`

Make sure this directories are available by typing: `mkdir -p ~/.config/i3/`